# Account id match

Tags: sql, teradata

There's a table in warehouse tab1 with column c1. there is another table that has been created tab2 and column c2. I want to know if c2 details are already there in tab1.c1 and display yes or no in a new column. anyone has any idea how to do it using sql?

Comment: Please add sample data for both tables to your question.

Comment: What is your desire table values?

Answer (score 0):

this is a rough approach I would use

```
SELECT 
t2.id, 
CASE WHEN t1.id IS NULL THEN 'NO'  ELSE 'YES' END AS DataExists 
FROM tab2 t2
--if c2 doesnt exist in the t1 this join will be null
LEFT JOIN tab1 t1 on t1.c1 = t2.c2
```

Comment: Your code would not execute.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert Thanks, I decided to switch the tables around, but only switched their alias. :/